# Alert when CPU usage more than % in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-administration

I want to send Alert via Email when CPU usage more than 80%

First, I test it when CPU Usage more than 1% then send email alert

I set Alert like this below

[image]

Then I open Task manager to see CPU usage it's always more than 1%

I go to my alert see on History tab it's not increase number of occures

[image]

So. anyone can guide me how to send alert via email when cpu usage more than X %

(I will do this on Memory X % too)

My Response Tab
[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you've set it to only alert if CPU usage falls below 0.01%

Comment: I fix it but it's still not work

Comment: @ChanomFirst can you help me i am also facing same issue? how you resolved it?

Comment: @ChanomFirst For me Aleter if counter=raise above is not working. Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You set **`Alert if counter`:**

[image]

**`falls below:`**

it should be

**`> than value`**

Also you probably didn't set **[`Response`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190670.aspx)**

Comment: @ChanomFirst Do you define response? Show Response tab

Comment: I defined response but number of occurs is 0